# Get data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using Firestore. I am not able to get the data from firestore. it shows some Firestore default response but not the data.
[image]

my cloud function is 
 if (req.method === 'POST' ) {

```
     const {
        type,
        dates,
        description
     } = req.body;
     const data = {
        type,
        dates,
        description
     }
     const docNameUBK = type;
     let incidentRef = 
         firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
         .doc(docNameUBK)
         .set(data)
         .then( response => {

             console.log("incidentRef---" + incidentRef);

             return firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc(docNameUBK).get()
                 .then(doc => {
                     if (!(doc && doc.exists)) {
                         return res.status(404).send({
                             error: 'Unable to find the document'
                         });
                     }
                     const data = doc.data();
                    return res.status(200).send(data);
                 }).catch(err => {
                     console.error(err);
                     return res.status(404).send({
                         error: 'Unable to retrieve the document',
                         err
                     });
                 });
         });

 }
```

I inserted the data which I could see in firestore. It looks perfect to me but I think I am not calling it in a proper way

//calendar-dates is document name

```
  this.firestore.collection('calendar-dates').ref
          .onSnapshot((firestoreResponse: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
            firestoreResponse.docs.forEach(outage => {
            });
            console.log('emitted data');
          });

      }
```

Comment: Your `forEach` loop is not doing anything with the data from Firestore. At its simplest you should log something in the loop, e.g. `firestoreResponse.docs.forEach(outage => { console.log(outage.data()); }
            });`

Comment: Try what Frank suggested. If this does not solve your issue then please provide more details on the errors or unexpected results you are getting.